# jest jumps out of function with promise

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm trying to test a function which calls another module's function which returns a promise,
The problem is that jest does not wait for completion of the myFunction and jumps out of it and treat it as a promise, as result section shows the "done" message is printed before "resolve" message. I have work around using [setImmediate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/setImmediate) but I rather not to use it and want to understand the reason.

the simplified version of the code is following:

The module which is mocked

```
// repo.js
const getItems = () => {
    console.log('real');
    return  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(
                () => resolve('result'), 1000);
        }
    );
}
module.exports = {
    getItems
};
```

Unit under test:

```
 // sample.js
const repo = require('./repo');

const myFunction = (req, res) => {
    console.log('myFunction');

    repo.getItems()
        .then(goals => {
            console.log('resolve');
            res.val = 'OK';
        }).catch(err => {
        console.log('reject');
        res.val = 'Failed';
    });

    return;
};

module.exports = {myFunction};
```

Test file:

```
// sample.test.js
const repo = require('./repo');
const sample = require('./sample');

const result = {
    'message': 'done'
};
describe('Tests for receiving items', () => {
        it('should call and be successful. ', () => {
            repo.getItems = jest.fn(() => {
                console.log('mocking');
                return new Promise((resolve) => ( resolve(result) ));
            });
            const response = {val: 'test'};
            const request = {};
            sample.myFunction(request, response);
            console.log('done');
            expect(response.val).toBe('OK');
        })
    }
);
```

The result is:

```
  console.log MySample\sample.js:5
    myFunction

  console.log MySample\sampel.test.js:11
    mocking

  console.log MySample\sampel.test.js:17
    done

  console.log MySample\sample.js:9
    resolve


Error: expect(received).toBe(expected)

Expected value to be (using ===):
  "OK"
Received:
  "test"
Expected :OK
Actual   :test
```

Answer (score -1):

The test you wrote reflects the correct usage, and you might say it fulfilled its purpose, because it uncovered a bug in your implementation.

To show what exactly went wrong, I will get rid of everything that is not needed, which leads to an even more minimal example. The following test file can be run by Jest and it reproduces your problem.

```
const myFunction = (res) => {
    Promise.resolve()
        .then(goals => {
            res.val = 'OK';
        }).catch(err => {
            res.val = 'Failed';
        });

    return;
};

it('should call and be successful. ', () => {
    const response = {val: 'test'};
    myFunction(response);
    expect(response.val).toBe('OK');
})
```

`myFunction` starts a promise (which resolves immediately here with no value) and returns nothing (`undefined`). You can also test the error part by using `Promise.reject` instead of `Promise.resolve`. When you call `myFunction(response)` the next line is executed when `myFunction` finishes. This is not when the promise actually finishes, but the function itself. The promise could take any amount of time and there is no way for you tell when it actually finished.

To be able to know when the promise finished, you need to return it, so you can use a `.then()` on it to execute something *after* the promise has been resolved. Both `.then()` and `.catch()` return a new promise which resolves with the returned value, which in this case is again `undefined`.  That means you need to do your assertion in the `.then()` callback. Similarly, Jest thinks that the test ends as you exit the function even though it should wait for the promise to be settled. To achieve this you can return the promise from the test and Jest will wait for its completion.

```
const myFunction = (res) => {
    // Return the promise from the function, so whoever calls myFunction can
    // wait for the promise to finish.
    return Promise.resolve()
        .then(goals => {
            res.val = 'OK';
        }).catch(err => {
            res.val = 'Failed';
        });
};

it('should call and be successful. ', () => {
    const response = {val: 'test'};
    // Return the promise, so Jest waits for its completion.
    return myFunction(response).then(() => {
        expect(response.val).toBe('OK');
    });
})
```

You can also use `async`/`await`, but keep in mind that you still need to understand how promises work, as it uses promises underneath. An `async` function always returns a promise, so Jest knows to wait for its completion.

```
it('async/await version', async () => {
    const response = {val: 'test'};
    // Wait for the promise to finish
    await myFunction(response);
    expect(response.val).toBe('OK');
})
```

Usually you would also return a value from the promise (in `.then()` or `.catch()`) instead of mutating an outer variable (`res`). Because if you use the same `res` for multiple promises, you will have a data race and the outcome depends on which promises finished first, unless you run them in sequence.

Comment: First I should say that the real application with this code functions perfectly well, the problem is testing with jest. I cannot return the promise from the function, the caller expects no returned value. I am only allowed to modify the object state. The caller is a third-party code so I cannot change the caller. The way you presenting the code is not the same as my code. myFunction does not return anything because the caller expects that myFunction does modification before ending and only looks into the object that it passed to myFunction.

Comment: *"the caller expects that myFunction does modification before ending"*, that means you can't do any asynchronous actions, because they are non-blocking and the function will always end before the asynchronous task finishes. If you don't return a promise or accept a continuation callback, it is pure luck whether the user reads the value before or after the asynchronous task has finished. Just because it happens to work in your case (presumably you're doing some work before reading it), doesn't mean it always works, and as the test shows, if the user uses it like that, it will fail.